# Transmit Heroku environment variables to Docker instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, docker, environment-variables

I build a RoR app on Heroku that must be run inside a Docker container. To do so I use the [official Dockerfile](https://github.com/heroku/docker-ruby). As it is very common with Heroku, I need a few add-ons to make this app fully operational. In production the variable `DATABASE_URL` is available within my app. But if I try some other add-ons that use environment variables ([Mailtrap](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mailtrap) in my case), variables aren't copied into the instance during runtime.

So my question is simple: **how can I make docker instances aware of the environment variables when executed on Heroku?**

As you may ask, I already know that we can specified an *environment* directive right in `docker-compose.yml`. I would like to avoid that in order to be able to share this file through the project repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't find any documentation about it but t appears that Heroku change very recently the way it handles [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) in Docker containers: **they are now replicated automatically** (values from `docker-compose.yml` are simply ignored).

Answer (score 1):

The workaround to not commit sensitive config files, would be to create a docker-compose.yml**.example** with empty fields and commit it, then add docker-compose.yml to .gitignore.

Since that's not very practical on heroku, you can use the `--env` docker switch to add any variable to the container's environment.

Like this: `docker run --env "MY_VAR=yolo" my_image:my_tag`

You could also serve a private docker-config.yml from a secure site, that heroku would have access to (that would be my preferred solution in your case).

Comment: We use a private S3 bucket for configs to do exactly what you reference in your last sentence.  yolo.

Comment: I like your idea of creating an example file for docker-compose.yml, it is pretty straightforward. Yet my concern is more about imitate the classic Heroku's workflow when adding an add-on (ie. add variables automatically to the running container on Heroku).